# Use AND/OR with Should.js (supertest)

Tags: javascript, should.js

I need you to know how i can use AND/OR with should.js 
I try to do something like that :

```
res.body[0].color.should.equal('blue').or('red');
```

It is possible with should ? I find nothing in documentation..Or i'm blind.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any 'or' operator, but you could do a 'match' regexp:

```
res.body[0].color.should.match(/^blue$|^red$/);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I will therefore look at this part of should!